# How to shut-down built-in Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, process, server

Whenever I ran my experimental Flask server, it used to say `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`.
It indeed did quit whenever I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. But after I ran a threaded Flask server, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> closes the server but does not exit the process. I must manually(painstakingly), kill the process, do `jobs` to determine the process number then `kill` it, wait until it is terminated before I restart the server. What is wrong with it? Do all threaded servers behave this way?

**Edit**

Do this in your `application.py`.

```
from flask-sse import sse

# your code...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/foo')
# code again
sse.publish() # anything you want

# much code

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(threaded=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Now run the file as `python application.py`. No need to do `flask run...`.
Now it says 
`Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Now try to press 
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Try reloading your webpage, it won't, implying the server closed. But look at the terminal, the process still hasn't terminated. 
If you look at the page `/foo`, you still seem to be getting events. It doesn't stop. It might imply that this thread hasn't stopped.
Now it is a painful effort to kill the process each time. Is there a solution?

Comment: By a `threaded Flask server` do you mean a thread that is running a Flask server? It is generally quite dangerous to abruptly kill a thread, as it can have a lock on other system resources or control over other threads.

Comment: @KartikKannapur By `threaded` Flask server I mean I have simply enabled `threaded=True`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @wgwz Just run your flask app as `threaded=True`. See you if you can terminate the process when `Ctrl + C` is pressed.

Comment: I did, and I did not have the same problem.

Comment: @wgwz Try using `flask-sse` module with `threaded=True`. I have a severe hunch that it is what is causing the trouble. Since sse has poor support from Python.

Comment: Just provide the MCVE. It's not too hard in this case

Comment: @wgwz Take a look again. I've edited the question.

Comment: This can happen if you run a threaded application and there's a thread running that has not been marked as a 'daemon thread'. Your main thread will exit while the background thread just sits there.